# Calculating time complexity of recursive method

Tags: java, time-complexity

I'm quite lost as to how to think when calculating time complexity of a recursive method.

[image]

Take the function above for example, would the timecomplexity be O(n) since it will take more time depending on whether the numbers are 13412421 and 1 or 20 and 5?

Comment: I think you should express the complexity in terms of `x` and `y`. Try to analyze how often the recursion takes place for fixed values of `y` (1, 2, ...) by varying `x` or for fixed values of `x` but varying `y`. I think this will lead you to the solution. Notice how the recursive return values sum, in steps of `1`, up to the final result. You probably know what the final result of the calculation is, don't you?

Comment: @GhostCat There's a typo in the OCR'ed code, last line reads `return (1+divRec(x-y,y));`, that should be `return (1+devRec(x-y,y));`

Comment: @Hintham And that is why we dont do OCR. So, lets do it the real way: dear OP, please replace that image with nicely formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity in Big O notation: The function `divRec` is being called `x/y` times so `O(n/y)= O(n)`. Complexity would be `linear`.

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate complexity of a simple algorithm which iterates once through an array to accomplish its task, its complexity is **O(n) - linear**, n being the length of the array.

Your algorithm is no different, only its complexity depends on **2 variables**. The code you wrote executes approximately x/y times, so if **n=x/y**, n is a **constant**. The complexity is then analogical to that of the example above - O(n), linear.